# Disabling constructor in Prophecy

Tags: php, symfony, prophecy

I have a Symfony class I am trying to mock using Prophecy. However, when I reveal the class it executes the constructor. Below is example code:

```
$mock = $this->prophesize('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile');
$mock->reveal();
```

which returns the exception

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException
```

which doesn't make sense to me as Prophecy is supposed to automatically disable the constructor?

Comment: I had the same problem and had to mock without prophecy: `$uploadedFile = $this->getMockBuilder(UploadedFile::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();`

Comment: @RenanTaranto I'll try that out, thank you. I ended up having to wrap the class and call it from the wrapper.

Comment: No problem. Creating a wrapper (adapter) may be a good idea too. Did it work for you? I will add as an answer since I believe it may help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and had to mock without prophecy:

```
$uploadedFile = $this->getMockBuilder(UploadedFile::class)->disableOriginalC‌​onstructor()->getMoc‌​k();
```

Probably related https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy/issues/58